# How define _WINDOWS in project settings in VS?

Tags: visual-studio

I need to connect framework, that says: "To use the framework define _WINDOWS in project's settings!", but I do not know where and what exactly should I write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed preprocessor definition.
Root: Project -> Properties -> Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor
In field Preprocessor Definitions add "_WINDOWS;"